# require selenium-webdriver does not work

Tags: ruby, selenium, windows-7, irb

I am getting errors when I use require "selenium-webdriver" in irb.  I am using Ruby 2.2.1 x64 on Windows 7 x64 and I have installed the selenium webdriver gem in C:\Ruby221-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.2.0\gems

The errors are as follows

```
 irb(main):002:0> require "selenium-webdriver"
    LoadError: cannot load such file -- selenium-webdriver
    from C:/Ruby221-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:5
    4:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby221-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:5
    4:in `require'
        from (irb):2
        from C:/Ruby221-x64/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
   irb(main):003:0> require "selenium-webdriver"
   LoadError: cannot load such file -- selenium-webdriver
        from C:/Ruby221-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:5
        4:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby221-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:5
        4:in `require'
        from (irb):3
        from C:/Ruby221-x64/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
irb(main):004:0>
```

Comment: u installed the gem ?

Comment: gem install  C:\Ruby221-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.2
    ebdriver
   ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'C:\Ruby221-x64\lib\ruby\ge
    0) in any repository
Fetching: websocket-1.2.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed websocket-1.2.2
Fetching: ffi-1.9.8-x64-mingw32.gem (100%)
Successfully installed ffi-1.9.8-x64-mingw32
Fetching: childprocess-0.5.6.gem (100%)
Successfully installed childprocess-0.5.6
Fetching: rubyzip-1.1.7.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rubyzip-1.1.7
............
Fetching: selenium-webdriver-2.45.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed selenium-webdriver-2.45.0
6 gems installed

Comment: @Arup is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: show the output of `gem list --local`..

Comment: gem list --local

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (1.2.6)
childprocess (0.5.6)
ffi (1.9.8 x64-mingw32)
io-console (0.4.3)
json (1.8.1)
minitest (5.4.3)
multi_json (1.11.0)
power_assert (0.2.2)
psych (2.0.8)
rake (10.4.2)
rdoc (4.2.0)
rubygems-update (2.4.7)
rubyzip (1.1.7)
selenium-webdriver (2.45.0)
test-unit (3.0.8)
websocket (1.2.2)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. This worked for me.

`gem update --system`